# Problem arrives when use default value for dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, default-value

when using a default value for a dictionary the comprehensive loop show empty list when asked to iterate for all key items

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict = {'whiz':1,'beerus':2,'vegeta':3,'goku':4}
dict = defaultdict(lambda : 'picalo')
print ([key for key in dict])
```

[]
process finished with exit code 0

[this code is run in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XekZ1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO. Please include a description of expected behavior with your questions, or you'll get answers like this:

*That's because there's nothing in the dictionary, it just has a default value!*

---

As far as I can tell the error you're making is you're *replacing* your dictionary, not giving it a default value.

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = {'whiz': 1,'beerus': 2,'vegeta': 3,'goku': 4}
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 'picalo', **my_dict)
print(my_dict)
```

Notice how I named the variable `my_dict` instead of `dict`, that's because `dict` is the "built-in" dictionary type and generally shouldn't be overwritten (to prevent bugs down the line).